# Check if user is valid Parse (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

My problem right now is that if something changes about the user in the database (manual change during testing), the client side cached user is not being updated. I know I need to use `fetch()` or one of the variants (background, if needed) but I don't really know how.

Here is my current code in AppDelegate to determine if to show login screen or proceed to the main app.

```
        // Decide which controller to go to
        self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        var sb: UIStoryboard? = nil
        if (PFUser.current() != nil) && (PFUser.current()?.isAuthenticated)! {
            sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        } else {
            sb = UIStoryboard(name: "SetupUser", bundle: nil)
        }

        let vc = sb?.instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This works most of the time, but if the user is updated or deleted form the DB the app will continue and crash later on due to errors updating/saving objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using `fetchInBackground` with completion block.

```
 PFUser.current()?.fetchInBackground(block : { (user, error) in
          if let user = user {
             //show Main
          }else {
             //showLogin
           }

    })
```

This way you perform your logic after fetching the user.

Comment: Should I have a placeholder view as its doing this to not just have a blank screen, and then put the code in the placeholder controller?

Comment: Yes , that would make a better user experience. It can be the same as the LaunchScreen View that you have but you can also make an animation to "distract" the user until the fetch is completed and then proceed with the Main/Login

Comment: Thanks for this. I had an idea similar to this but couldn't figure out how to implement it.